# Javascript confusing order of execution

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I was playing around with `reverse()` to see how it works and came across this interaction that I can't understand at all. Here is the initial code:

```
let muhArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

let reversedArray = muhArray.reverse();

console.log(`muhArray: ${muhArray}`);

console.log(`reversedArray: ${reversedArray}`);
```

This returns:

muhArray: 5,4,3,2,1 (Original array changed as well)

reversedArray: 5,4,3,2,1

I figured that since `reverse()` reverses arrays in-place, even if it is an initilization, it changes the original `muhArray` anyways. So I created a copy(`muhArrayCopy`) to preserve the original array.

```
let muhArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

let muhArrayCopy = muhArray;

console.log(`muhArrayCopy: ${muhArrayCopy}`);

let reversedArray = muhArray.reverse();

console.log(`reversedArray: ${reversedArray}`);
```

This returns:

muhArrayCopy: 1,2,3,4,5

reversedArray: 5,4,3,2,1

Up until this point everything seems fine, but changing the order made me realise `muhArray.reverse()` affects already declared and initialized `muhArrayCopy` as well.

```
let muhArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

let muhArrayCopy = muhArray;

let reversedArray = muhArray.reverse();

console.log(`muhArrayCopy: ${muhArrayCopy}`);

console.log(`reversedArray: ${reversedArray}`);
```

Such order returns:

muhArrayCopy: 5,4,3,2,1

reversedArray: 5,4,3,2,1

Is this maybe a code execution order thing? I have read about hoisting but that does not seem to explain it, as far as I can understand. I am all new to programming so I have little to no knowledge about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try and use the rest parameter by cloning the array instead of referring to it: `const muhArrayCopy = [...muhArray]`. Not 100% sure if that will work accordingly, but it's worth a try

Comment: It is because Javascript is [Object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) so the copy of a variable will point to the

Comment: `let muhArrayCopy = muhArray;` does not create an actual copy of the array, it simply gives it "a second name", as non primitives are copied by reference. If you want to create a real copy that "lives" independently from the original array, you can use the spread operator (`let muhArrayCopy = [...muhArray];`) or any other suitable method that creates a new array (e.g. `let muhArrayCopy = muhArray.map(item => item;);` or `let muhArrayCopy = muhArray.slice();`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js is call by `reference`, so

```
let muhArrayCopy = muhArray;
```

does not create a copy, it puts the `reference` of variable in the other one, so both are affected when something happens to the  other.

```js
let muhArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

let muhArrayCopy = [...muhArray];

let reversedArray = muhArray.reverse();

console.log(`muhArrayCopy: ${muhArrayCopy}`);

console.log(`reversedArray: ${reversedArray}`);
```

this should solve it. here `[...muhArray]` we are creating a copy of the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing unexpected happening here.  In the first code snippet, you print the array copy *before* reversing the original array.  Keep in mind that the "copy" still points to the original array.  In the second snippet, you print the copy *after* reversing the original source.

Answer (score 0):

`[Array.prototype.reverse()][1]` from definition *The reverse() method reverses an array in place and returns the reference to the same array*

So when you apply reverse to an array, it changes the parent array as well.

If you want to make your original array unchanged, you have to copy the original array to an another memory location and reverse it.

Assigning a variable to another will copy the memory location of the same variable. So what ever changes made to the existing variable will be reflected to the assigned variable as well

You should not copy the variable, instead you have to clone it and assign it to another variable. This can be done using Deep Copy and Shallow Copy

[Read more about Deep Copy v/s Shallow Copy here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/3-ways-to-copy-objects-in-javascript/)

Since the variable here is an array, just clone it with Spread operator and reverse it.

Working Example

```js
let muhArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

let muhArrayCopy = muhArray;

let reversedArray = [ ...muhArray ].reverse();

console.log(`muhArrayCopy: ${muhArrayCopy}`);

console.log(`reversedArray: ${reversedArray}`);
```